# A different version of "Attack on D" from near the end of season 2 episode 12?

Tags: music, attack-on-titan

So I heard this song in *Attack on Titan* towards the end of season 2 episode 12 and when I compared it to the soundtrack, I found out it was called "Attack on D".

However, the song in the actual episode (episode 12) has a piano part in it and the 'la la la' part only comes in towards the end of the song.

Is it a different song? If so, is it available in the OST?